# Goes to a file and prints only the words that don't have any digits in them

Tags: python, python-3.2

Also I need to make the program show the words that DO have digits in thee digits in them SEPERATELY

```
f = open("lolpa.txt", "r")

list1 = (f)
temp = []

for item in list1:
    if "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "0"  in item:
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        print(item)
```

is what i have so far, but it for some reason shows all the words.

EDIT: The lolpa.txt is just a file for comparison

EDIT: If that would change anything , I'm using python 3.2.

Comment: `if in item:` looks wrong. Are you sure that's what you have? Also, someone fixed your formatting but you changed it back.

Comment: Well, earlier, between those two there were "1", "2", "3", "4" and until 9. I guess i messed it up while copypasting, thanks for telling, ill check it.

Comment: Python automatically concatenates strings that are right next to each other, so `"1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "0"` is interpreted as `"1234567890"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will get you started, question isn't very clear.

```
with open("lolpa.txt") as f:
    for word in f.readline().split(): # assuming all words are on the first line
        digits = [c for c in word if c.isdigit()]
        if digits: # digits list is not empty
            print(' '.join(digits)) # shows digits with space in between
        else:
            print(word) # prints word normally
```

Comment: Thanks jamylak, it now shows the digits only, without the words though :c

Comment: @Kichrootra What does your file look like? This example file works fine for me: http://pastebin.com/aUYKqyHj

Comment: the file is .txt and what's in there is artur artu4 i5 is awes0me awesome. what your script does is only show the digits.

Comment: @Kichrootra is that all on the one line?

Comment: I'm usin python 3.2 if it changes anythin.

Comment: Yup! Thanks you helped me A LOT. I'm serious :) you are nice

Comment: And one more thing. How do I make it so it will show the words without numbers in one line too? When I get the .split() out, it prints every letter after an "enter"

Comment: not sure exactly what you want from what you have told me, if you make a new question and show the code you have used and your desired output along with a sample input then someone may be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following will put whole words having numbers in them in one file and without numbers in another.

```
f = open('lolpa.txt', 'r')
d = open('lolpa_with_digit.txt', 'w')
nd = open('lolpa_without_digit.txt', 'w')
rowlist = (f)
temp = []

for line in rowlist:
    words = line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        word = word.strip()
        has_digit = False
        for char in word:
            if char.isdigit():
                has_digit = True
        if has_digit:
            d.write(word + '\n')
        else:
            nd.write(word +'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regular expression expert but this should work(of course you'd have to loop over each line yadayada):

```
import re
prog = re.comile(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b')
result = prog.findall(your_line_here)
```

result would then be a list of all the words

Comment: Why not directly `re.findall()`, without `prog = …`?

Comment: @EOL re.findall(pattern,string) is equivalent to what I have.  the prog saves you from compiling each time(so you are more efficient).  but yes, it hardly matters in this case

Comment: You're right about compiling. If you really care about efficiency, then it is even more efficient to do `prog = re.compile(…).findall`.  That said, I always argue to my students that `prog = …` unnecessarily increases the cognitive burden of reading the program: it actually means that `prog` will be reused and that people must keep this variable somewhere in their mind. So, while your code is *functionally* equivalent to not using an intermediate variable, I never encourages people to create unnecessary variables.